# DNS Inconsistency with Google Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am dealing with some weird inconsistency issues with the dns to my subdomain, and was hoping someone would be able to shed some light!

I have a domain purchased through Google Domains and have a need to use the main domain, and a single subdomain for my api service. With Route 53, i have 2 hosted zones, one for the main, and one for the subdomain, each providing the 4 NS configs, and two aliases back to my Elastic Beanstalk nodes for the www & non www calls.

For my main domain, using WhatsMyDomain, the propagation is pretty much worldwide at all times, but when it comes to my subdomain, it is intermittent and changes throughout the day, where it was working in one location earlier on, it will then stop working.

In Google Domains, i have all 8 NS configurations set in my DNS settings.

I feel like im missing just one piece of something, just can't figure it out

Comment: Chances are your question would be a lot more easily answered with the actual domain and subdomain in question.

Comment: *"i have all 8 NS configurations set in my DNS settings."*  That would definitely cause bad things to happen.  Why do you have two different hosted zones?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael - sqlbot for his return question, never even thought about just trying it by adding an alias to the subdomain in the original Hosted Zone! In the docs on AWS, they do provide info on having 2 different zones, which i think thats what i stumbled across when i first started, but i believe there is a bit more setup involved in that route!

Just made the switch, gonna see if this solves the issue!